# data written to text file is partially corrupt and irretrievable

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, ofstream

```
template <class T>
void savetext(T *a, char const *b) //writes to text file inside .sln however the text file is corrupt
{
    ofstream fout(b, ios::out);
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
        fout << a[i] << endl;
    cout << "Text file successfully written to." << endl;
}

template <class T>
void gettext(T *a, char const *b) //this is where the error occurs: inside the text file it puts the right values along with piles of junk. Why is this? 
{

    ifstream fin(b, ios::in);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
    cout << "File opened. Now displaying .txt data..." << endl; 
        for (int i = 0; a[i]!= '\0'; i++)
        {
            fin >> a[i];
        }
        cout << "Data successfully read." << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n1 = 5, n2 = 7, n3 = 6;
    int a[n1], x, y, z;
    float b[n2] = {};
    char c[n3] = "";

    //Begin writing files to text files which I name herein.
    cout << "Writing data to text 3 text  files." << endl;
    savetext(a, "integer.txt");
    savetext(b, "float.txt");
    savetext(c, "string.txt");
    cout << endl;

    //Retrieve the text in the files and display them on console to prove that they work.  
    cout << "Now reading files, bitch!" << endl;
    gettext(a, "integer.txt");
    gettext(b, "float.txt");
    gettext(c, "string.txt");
    cout << endl;

    return 0;

system("PAUSE");
}
```

Hello, and good evening. I have a C++ program that is currently writing data (integer, floats and chars) to 3 separate text files. However, when it writes the data to the text files two things happen: the data is inside the text file, but so is a bunch of unintelligible wingdings text and large numbers and large negative numbers -- data which I never entered in.

As a result of this, **I'm not able to retrieve the information from the text file and I'm not able to display the information of the text file.** How do I solve that problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is using std::vector instead of static array ok for this? If your program reads a variable number of bytes from the file, dynamically allocated container (such as std::vector) is better than a static array that can only hold a fixed number of bytes. Since the file size can be bigger than the memory available, processing the file as we read it from hard disk is a good idea. This way avoids storing all data from file to the memory at the same time. Also have to think about endianness and unicode encoding if you do cross platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are writing uninitialized data to your files.

Comment: Hm. I'm under the impression that I initialized them in the `main()` did I not? `char c[n3] = "";`, `float b[n2] = {};`, and `int a[n1], x, y, z;` are not initializations? If they aren't, where and what should I do? Thanks Rich.

Comment: The string is "empty", which means the first character is \0.  I don't recall, but I think you need a value in the braces for b to have an initialized value.  However, a, x, y, and z are all uninitialized.

Comment: Change your function to use cout instead of your file stream and see what you get.

Comment: Ok, so I changed `fout` to `cout` and it _did_ display the values inside the text and they were again, partially right and partially wrong. To be more accurate, it displayed the right values followed by a bunch of wingdings. Also, I want to mention that one of the constraints I have is to use a function that writes the files and use a function that reads the files and displays them. So two functions are needed. Though, thankfully, we've been able to make the step of displaying the text data into the console...so that's a start. Thanks for helping Rich.

Comment: Ok, so the next problem is that your loop condition is only valid for strings. - or you need to be sure that the last value in every array is a zero.  Or you can switch to std::array or std::vector constructs that have internal knowledge of just how many entries are in the array being output.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to digest what you're saying. So there is a hiccup around `a[i] != '\0'` ...I was thinking, and maybe you could corroborate this...could I stick `const int n` inside `savetext` a la `savetext(T *a, char const *b, const int n)` and then instead of `a[i] != '\0'` I use `a[i] < n`...? would that work you think? Or is there still something structurally wrong? Thanks again Rich. Much appreciated.

Comment: Examine the loop in saveText carefully.  Note that it loops until the value of the array element in question is zero.  Strings are the only 'array' that are null terminated.  So the loop will march happily along through your memory until it just happens to trip over a zero.

Comment: That was actually the solution. Thank you for shepherding me Rich. Have a wonderful Superbowl weekend.